# Llenar contenedor solo con lo necesario

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: imagen]

Buenas! ¿como puedo hacer para que mi contenedor principal tenga la altura necesaria para cubrir mis elementos? Por ejemplo, quiero que el contenedor solo llegue a la linea roja, para que no abarque tanto espacio innecesario, ya trate poniéndole un ~heigth:15vw;~ pero también tengo que cambiar el heigth de el otro contenedor ¿No hay otra manera? siento que esta manera esta mal, mucho código y no siento que sea adecuado. Muchas gracias

```css
html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 62.5%;
        }
        
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        
        body {
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            line-height: 2;
            background-image: url("../img/35.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        
        .contenedor {
            width: 95%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        
        .centrar-texto {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .logo {
            height: 30rem;
            width: 30rem;
        }
        
        .contenedor-nav {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
            /* width: 100%;
            height: 10%; */
        }
        
        .elemento {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: 'montserrat';
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        
        .navegacion-principal {
            /* min-width: 80vw; */
            display: flex;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 3rem;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Public+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Raspados Isla</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="contenedor-nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="/img/logoo copia.png" alt="Logo Raspados Isla">
            </a>
        </div>


        <nav class="navegacion-principal">
            <a href="#" class="elemento">Raspados</a>
            <a href="#" class="elemento">Tejuino</a>
            <a href="#" class="elemento">Tepache</a>
            <a href="#" class="elemento">Tuba</a>
            <a href="#" class="elemento">Cerveza De Raíz</a>
        </nav>

    </div>
    <h1 class="centrar-texto">¿Mucho calor?</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es establecer la propiedad `min-height` al div que contiene el navbar con una altura mínima que sabes que va a tener el menú si o sí (por ejemplo el tamaño del logo). En ese caso, si la altura del div tuviera que ser más debido al contenido, este se agrandaría hasta adecuarse, siendo como mínimo la altura que le hayas establecido.

Te dejo un ejemplo en el que al div le he puesto un `min-height` de 50px pero en cambio la imagen tiene una altura de 120px. Como puedes observar el div se adapta al contenido agrandándose hasta los 120px.

```css
.divAjustable{
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#imagenPeque{
   height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divAjustable">
  <img id="imagenPeque" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/taiga/taiga1608/taiga160800047/64521425-cascada-en-el-bosque-de-oto%C3%B1o-de-color-amarillo-paisaje-vertical.jpg">
</div>
```